# Using awk to summarize data and sort output then sum result of a column

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

LOGFILE's Raw Data:

```
   Data1 12:00 Sep 28 COUNT= 100
   Data1 12:00 Sep 30 COUNT= 8
   Data1 12:00 Oct 02 COUNT= 4
   Data1 12:00 Oct 01 COUNT= 3
   Data1 12:00 Oct 05 COUNT= 4
   Data1 12:00 Oct 01 COUNT= 3
   Data1 12:00 Sep 29 COUNT= 5
   Data1 12:00 Sep 29 COUNT= 5
```

Code :

```
grep "Data1" $LOGFILE | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6|"sort -k1,1r -k2,2 -u"}' | awk '{sum+=$4} {print "\t"$1,$2,$3,$4} END {print "\t\tTotal=","\033[44m"sum"\033[m"}'
```

Result :

```
    Sep 28 COUNT= 100
    Sep 29 COUNT= 5
    Sep 30 COUNT= 8
    Oct 01 COUNT= 3
    Oct 02 COUNT= 4
    Oct 05 COUNT= 4
           Total= 124
```

this code does 3 things:

- searches for any line containing Data1 records to grab the 3rd, 4th, 5th & 6th column (LOGFile's columns)
- then sort them reversely (r) by result's first column (-k1,1) and normally by result's second column (-k2,2) and excludes any repetition (-u)
- then sums the result's last (4th of awk's result) column to be displayed as "Total"

**is there a better way to write this code ?**

Edit1 :

```
awk '/Data1/{print $3,$4,$5,$6|"sort -k1,1r -k2,2 -u"}' $LOGFILE | awk '{sum+=$4} {print "\t"$1,$2,$3,$4} END {print "\t\tTotal=","\033[44m"sum"\033[m"}'
```

Comment: This sounds more like a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) type of question?

Comment: should i post it where the link leads and remove it from here?

Comment: If you plan to post to code review, then yes. (many don't like double-posts across sites)

Comment: If i can, I prefer to leave it here to help others as i was searching for this code and glued it from different post in case someone needs the exact result as me

Comment: You can always simplify when you start out with a `grep`. Move that to `awk '/Data1/{print $3,$4,$5,$6 ...}' $LOGFILE`. I would move the `sort` outside of the `awk`, but it may not matter. Good luck.

Comment: without a year component the sorting, by month, will produce: `Apr, Aug, Dec, Feb ...`; is this the desired result?

Comment: @markp-fuso the log wont get data for more than few month, but yes in case it keeps loging to the next year it will have to be sorted by year too.

Comment: @shellter Thanks, it looks better than before, but is there a way to just use one awk !!

Comment: At the "expense" of sorting extra data, you could do `sort .... FILE | awk {...as above ; sum+=$4}END{print "sum="sum}'`. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter which is more resource efficient ? is it harder to awk or to sort?

Comment: if you're sorting a massive file, only to extract 1 day's data, then you're better to filter it first. But for "normal" loads, the `sort | awk 'all in one'` should be fine. Test it both ways, and possibly 10X the normal data and see if it is significant. launching a extra process in a pipeline is generally not that expensive but it one process does something that is really time-consuming, then it makes sense to process only the minimal amount of data. `sort` programs are part o the OS and are highly optimized, but 10X data, will be ~ 10X seconds compared to 1X. ...

Comment: Unless  your use case requires "as-fast-as-possible,really!" turnaround time, then anything less that 30 seconds to process is usually fast enough. Let your use-case and worst-case growth of data be your guide about how much effort to put into making a program run as fast as possible. (Always nice to do that, but as with most things in programming, there are tradeoffs that you're getting paid the big money to decide about ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: Several minor edits in both messages above (please dbl-check(reload page)). Good luck.